# Oracle server date format

Tags: sql, eclipse, date, report, locale

I've got a report made with Eclipse which builds a table with `Strings` and `Dates` through a SQL query, and running it locally it works fine, but when I bring it on my oracle server the day and month are switched, not visually, but just the data, let me do an example:

Dates generated locally on Eclipse (dd/mm/yy):

```
01/06/17 (1st jun)
31/12/17 (31st dec)
```

Same dates on report generated on server (dd/mm/yy):

```
06/01/17 (6th jan)
12/31/17 <- which shows the row retrieved by the query but leaves a blank space in the "my_date" column
```

Does anybody have an idea on why this happens? Thanks.

**EDIT: these are my SESSION parameters, I can't change them right now but I'll keep you updated if that works out. Thanks!**

[image: Session]

Comment: Dates are stored as a special type called `DATE1, it has no format. Try your NLS_DATEFORMAT setting, ie, it formats on display, not on storage

Comment: You can try `to_char(date_val)` to fix the date format

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. For example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
```

or:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY MM DD';
```

or whatever other format you like. Check the [fine manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119)